# mpi process ids

Tags: process, mpi, pid

I would like to get the process ids of an mpi application which I start with mpirun/mpiexec tools.

For example I run my code with lets say 8 processes and want to get the process ids of all these 8 processes right at the beginning of the execution to give to another tool as an input.

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: why not just use the rank?

Comment: you could also check via htop but like HPC mark suggested it could change every run

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that there is any MPI library routine which will return the pid of the o/s process which is running an MPI process.  To be absolutely precise I don't think that the MPI standard requires there to be a one:one mapping between MPI processes and o/s processes, nor any other cardinality of mapping, though I don't think I've ever used an MPI implementation where there wasn't a one:one mapping between the different views of processes.

All that aside, why not simply use `getpid` if you are on Linux machine ?  Each MPI process should get its own pid.  I guess there is a Windows system call which does the same thing but I don't know much about Windows.

Comment: There was a suggestion for MPI-3 that didn't make it to the standard, called _endpoints_. It would have allowed for one OS process to host many MPI ranks and to assign them to arbitrary threads of execution. According to the standard, each rank identifies a separate process in a process group, but "processes are
implementation-dependent objects", i.e. it doesn't necessary mean that an MPI process is an OS process.