# How to know the which core a process is running on in MPI?

Tags: mpi

I am currently working on a project where I need to know the coreid of the processor on which the the process currently runs on in MPI? There is a function in MPI called **MPI_Get_processor_name( char *name, int *resultlen )**. This only gives the name of the node on which the process is running. I want to know the id of the core on which it is running? Is it possible? If it is so can anyone give me the code snippet for doing it?

Thank you

Comment: Read my answer to a similar question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569577/mpi-process-ids/14572391#14572391 -- and change those parts of it which need to be changed to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am asking for the coreid (on which core of the system (in an intra node environment) ) the process is running. I am not asing for the process_id (pid). For that I can use the linux system call getpid().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which gives the coreids for each process on which they are bound. This needs the hwloc library as suggested by  Hristo Iliev in the previous answer's comments.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include <hwloc.h>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        int rank, size;
        cpu_set_t mask;
        long num;
        int proc_num(long num);

        hwloc_topology_t topology;
        hwloc_cpuset_t cpuset;
        hwloc_obj_t obj;


        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

        hwloc_topology_init ( &topology);
        hwloc_topology_load ( topology);

        hwloc_bitmap_t set = hwloc_bitmap_alloc();
        hwloc_obj_t pu;
        int err;

        err = hwloc_get_proc_cpubind(topology, getpid(), set, HWLOC_CPUBIND_PROCESS);
        if (err) {
        printf ("Error Cannot find\n"), exit(1);
        }

        pu = hwloc_get_pu_obj_by_os_index(topology, hwloc_bitmap_first(set));
        printf ("Hello World, I am %d and pid: %d coreid:%d\n",rank,getpid(),hwloc_bitmap_first(set));

        int my_coreid = hwloc_bitmap_first(set);
        int all_coreid[size];
        hwloc_bitmap_free(set);
        hwloc_topology_destroy(topology);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: The line "cpu_set_t mask" gives a compiler error on my version of hwloc, but fortunately the variable is unused anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your question assumes that each MPI process runs bound to a single CPU core. This is not the default behaviour for many cluster MPI implementations. For example Open MPI has the necessary binding machinery but one has to explicitly enable it with the `--bind-to-core` or `--bind-to-socket` option. On the other hand, modern Intel MPI versions enable binding by default for performance reasons. Because of that discrepancy, with most cluster MPI implementations `MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME` simply returns the hostname of the execution node since no specific processor is identifiable in the general case.

When each process runs bound to a core, the binding can usually be obtained by reading the affinity mask of the process. This is OS dependent, but there are libraries that can abstract that away, for example the [hwloc library](http://www.open-mpi.de/projects/hwloc/) (part of Open MPI, but developed as a completely separate project and hence usable on its own). Reading the affinity mask is also possible in the general case - when a process is not bound, the affinity mask would simply match the system affinity mask (i.e. execution allowed on all processors).

There are platforms where binding is part of the system hardware working, e.g. IBM Blue Gene. There each MPI process executes on one and only well identifiable processor and `MPI_Get_processor_name` returns a unique string value in each calling process.

Comment: @ Hristo Iliev. Thank You for your very good reply. Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to up vote. Did you use hwloc library. If so can you please to tell me how to go about getting the coreid of the process running. Actually I found one more sched_getcpu(). Does this give correct results? I tried to verify it by using taskset command. The results are not as expected.

Comment: `sched_getcpu()` is very `glibc` specific and it returns the CPU on which the thread is currently executing. If the thread is not bound to a specific core, then the return values from successive invocations might differ as the thread might be migrated to other cores. `sched_getaffinity()` is the call which returns the active affinity mask.

Comment: How to extract coreid from the mask which is passed as a parameter to the sched_getaffinity() function?

Comment: Examine every bit of the returned mask. If the process is bound to a single CPU only, then only one bit in the mask (possibly two or more bits if the process is bound to all core hyperthreads) would be set. If no binding is active, then the mask would be all possible bits set.

Comment: Illiev I contacted hwloc developors list and Open MPI developers  for asking them to give me a way to find the bindings of all the processes inside an MPI application. They couldn't give me a satisfying reply. Do you know some way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use hwloc.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your previous question about hwloc. It provides binding information, so you could query the machine topology and compare the allowed CPU set for each process with that topology in order to discover if binding is in effect. Also `MPI_Get_processor_name` provides you the hostname of the node where the calling rank is executing.

Comment: That's ok. I figured it out by going through the hwloc documentation and came up with the code below. Thank You